# What does creep affect?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I'm fairly new to the game and am trying to get better as Zerg. From watching some replays of higher level players, I often see Zerg players spreading creep like crazy as fast as they can.

My question is, what exactly are the things that creep affects?

I know that Zerg units walk faster on creep, but are there other benefits?

Things like:

- non-Zerg walk slower
- Faster health regeneration for Zerg
- Damage bonusses for Zerg

So can anyone shed some light?

Comment: While it may seem a trivial distinction, to me the most important part of creep spreading is really the "creep tumor" spreading, as the tumors give you vision.

Comment: terran and protoss buildings can't be built on creep as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just Zerg movement.

Zerg (ground) units  move about 30% faster on creep (notable exceptions being: Queen, Hydralisk and Drones).

Additionally Zerg can build on creep and non-Zerg structures *cannot* be built on creep.  You can actually use an Overlord to spread creep at a number of expansions to slow down your opponent's expansion rate.  Zerg structures off creep will slowly lose life and eventually die.

The following units/buildings can produce creep:

- Hatchery
- Creep Tumor (built from the Queen and other Creep Tumors)
- Overlord (Overseers **Cannot**, additionally this is temporary)
- Nydus Worm (the Worm, not the Network)

Creep will evaporate if left without a production source near by.  Its important to note that creep evaporates from the edge inward.  As a result, if you remove creep production in an area that is not covered by, but is surrounded by, creep production, the creep will not evaporate.

---

Since people asked the following units are affected by creep in different ways:

- Queen: 170%
- Hydralisk: 50%
- Drone: 0%

Comment: Something I've been curious about with regards to the movespeed bonus - does it affect flying units too? Nobody makes mention of it, so I've always been curious. And for the second one, does that "expansion slow down" backfire against a Zerg opponent?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect flying units.

Comment: Rather than moving 30% faster on creep, the Queen moves *much* slower *off* creep.

Comment: @WillfulWizard that's a matter of perspective.

Comment: @Grace You can build Hatcheries off creep so there is no benefit to having creep there first.  You can build Spine Crawlers before the Hatchery but since they can be uprooted this is a small benefit.

Comment: Well, since they die off (which I didn't know until now, good to know), then it doesn't help much to have just the nonproducers. But you can lay down a hatchery, as well as start off some defensive structures at the same time, rather than wait for completion of the building, aye? At least, assuming that the hatchery doesn't produce creep until it is actually completed, so there is nothing while building. It's nothing revolutionary or anything, but just something I figured is consideration of some manner.

Comment: If an Overlord is dropping creep at an expansion, you can indeed plant crawlers right away instead of waiting for the creep that comes when the Hatch finishes. I do this for vulnerable expansions. Dropping creep to slow enemy expansions works well (for non-Zerg opponents).

Comment: The fact that creep prevents non zerg buildings from being constructed makes zerg much harder to cannon rush than other races.  just plop down a tumour (just out of range of the cannons), and you have a nice huge safe zone that the cannons will never be able to intrude upon.

Comment: I think that Nydus Canal endpoint also spawn creeps

Comment: I did not know you could build creep tumors from other creep tumors...

Comment: @Juan oh yeah, that's how you build your creep highways

Comment: Each creep tumor can spawn one creep tumor, fyi.

Comment: Also, the more creep tumors you have in one area, the faster the creep grows. I like to have two creep tumors side by side to build my creep highway - much faster.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "notable exceptions being: Queen, Hydralisk and Drones". Particularly how does it affect Hydralisks and Drones differently?

Comment: @tzenes My comment was not intended to switch the perspective, (although I do believe it is useful to think of the Queen on creep as being normal and off creep being the change) but to clarify the way in which the Queen is an exception, which you didn't: for the Queen, the speed difference is greater than 30%. I could have phrased my comment better to do that, sorry. Also, workers move the same speed on and off creep? I do not know how Hydras behave, although I'm betting you can fill us in on that as Dave requested. :)

Comment: How much faster/slower is the Hydralisk off creep?

Comment: Hydralisks are 50% faster on creep, Queens are 170% faster, and other units are 30% faster [(Source)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XepT2daJqYY)

Comment: @Wik you'll notice I added those numbers three days ago

Comment: Probably something of note here as well are the movement speeds of the uprooted crawlers on and off creep. They're much akin to the queen's.

Answer (score 4):

The one other affect of creep I know (beyond tzene's answer) is that Zerg buildings will lose health and eventually die if they are off creep. For example if a Hatchery is destroyed, the creep will start to disappear, and eventually other buildings there will die.

I believe Spine Crawlers and Spore Crawlers lose health when they are uprooted if they are not on creep as well.

The buildings that can be built off creep and survive without it are Hatcheries and Nydus Worm exits (which both generate creep) and Vespene Extractors.

Comment: It's true, Zerg buildings die when off-creep. This makes lunacy like the dreaded [double Evolution Chamber rush](http://www.shokzguide.com/starcraft-2-videos/double-proxy-evolution-chamber-rush-brokenrythm/) possible. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your units move faster on creep. Additionally, buildings placed off of creep will die. Moving faster is a huge advantage, and is absolutely worth covering anywhere you need to move units quickly with creep for.

Answer (score 1):

Other races can not place buildings on creep.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to keeping buildings alive and increasing movement speed of units, creep tumors give you *vision*. This is a huge advantage since it makes it much harder for your enemy to surprise you with an attack.

If you see where the enemy army moves around on the map it gives you more time to react and get your troops in place to defend.