# Does creep or do creep tumors give vision?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

In reference to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/what-does-creep-affect), which gives vision, the creep or the tumors?  Also what about dealing with elevation and creep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the Tumors.  They act like any other building (though are invisible once built) and provide vision like any other building.

You cannot own creep so it belongs to noone and thus its impossible to know who it would provide vision to (imagine a ZvZ).

Comment: I think we should draw a line down the middle of the creep. We can use duct tape. This is my side of the creep, that's your side. You have to walk slower when you're on my side. Hey, your baneling nest is hanging over the line onto my side! Don't make me call the GM!!

Comment: @Wik I think I laughed for about 5 minutes about this comment

Comment: one day i hope to play in a ZvZ where our creep highways meet and we start planting tumours on "each others" creep.  Of course,ZvZ seems so rare, and when it happens it is always so hectic for me i can barely keep my 2nd base alive, let alone worry about creep highways.

Comment: ZvZ is kind of the ninja match up: You know it exists but nobody has actually seen it!

Comment: Tumors don't act like any other building. It's more like immobile units. You don't need to destroy every creep tumor to win the game.

Comment: Troll creep tumour blocking an enemy Z from making a hatch is priceless.